# php get curl posted data

Tags: php, curl

I am calling a php api via curl

```
ncServerURL='http://myserver/acertify.php'
  # binaryptr = open('sampleamex.xml','rb').read()
  # print binaryptr
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(pycurl.URL, ncServerURL)
  c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
  c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
  c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
  header=["Content-type: text/xml","SOAPAction:run",'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8','Content-Length: '+str(len(xmldata))]
  # print header
  c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, header)
  c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, "xml="+str(xmldata))
  import StringIO
  b = StringIO.StringIO()
  c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
  c.perform()
  ncServerData = b.getvalue()
  return ncServerData
```

and posting xml data. in acertify.php and i am not able to xml data in php files , i am working on a project , what i don't know in this , how can i get curl posted data in this file .

```
<?php

echo "hi";
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_POST);
// print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

Comment: solved by echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting POST data in php, then at first glance looks like you are posting a single field `c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, "xml="+str(xmldata))`

so it should just be `$_POST['xml']`

And if you mean reading data with curl as a response, then curl should have returntransfer option on execution (i'm not familiar with python syntax)

Comment: my $_POST['xml'] is coming blank

Comment: maybe you should pass post params as an array?